# menu aligned with navbar

Tags: html, css, menu

Can someone help me put my menu on the left next to my navbar. 
As you can see the icon floats above the navigation which extends the top bar, 
both the icon and navigation inside the top bar need to be aligned next to each other.

```css
body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#top-bar{
 background-color: black;
 padding: 1%;
 width: auto;
}

#left-menu{
 display: inline-block; 
}

#navigation{
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: red;
}

#navigation ul{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#navigation ul li{
 float: left;
}

#navigation ul li a{
 text-decoration: none;
 margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  
  <div id="top-bar">
   <div id="left-menu">
    <img src="icons/menu.png"/>
   </div>

   <div id="navigation">
    <ul>
     <li><a class="link" href="#"> Home     </li>
     <li><a class="link" href="#"> About Us </li>
     <li><a class="link" href="#"> Contact  </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>

 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is remove `width: 100%` from `#navigation`, and instead give it `float: left`.

You've also forgotten to close your `<a>` tags.

I've fixed this in the following:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#top-bar {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 1%;
  width: auto;
}

#left-menu {
  display: inline-block;
}

#navigation {
  /* width: 100%; */
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
}

#navigation ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#navigation ul li {
  float: left;
}

#navigation ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="top-bar">
    <div id="left-menu">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100" />
    </div>
    <div id="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="link" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="link" href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a class="link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

If you want to ensure that they're the same height, you're looking to give your `#navigation` a `line-height` property that equals the height of the image, along with `display: block`. This can be seen in the following:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#top-bar {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 1%;
  width: auto;
}

#left-menu {
  display: inline-block;
}

#navigation {
  /* width: 100%; */
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
}

#navigation ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  /* display: inline-block; */
  display: block;
  line-height: 100px; /* Equal to the height of the image */
  overflow: hidden;
}

#navigation ul li {
  float: left;
}

#navigation ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="top-bar">
    <div id="left-menu">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100" />
    </div>
    <div id="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="link" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="link" href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a class="link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: But now my navbar is not centered anymore instead of float left I gave it a float right, because the icon needs to be left and navbar at the right side. How can I put my navbar in the center with the icon at left side.